# Is it bad style to include a list in an abstract?

Tags: paper-submission, abstract

If I am writing a study paper and I have given some descriptors as to which systems will be measured (things such as "openness" and "availability" in my case) is it acceptable for me to provide a list of this after with a short sentence expanding on what metrics that word in intended to include?

e.g.

- Openness - Measured by the proportion of the human population has access and the ease of entry for those who meet the requirements
- etc...

Comment: I think you have to look at published literature in your field.  In my field (economics) that would be very unusual, enough so that I would absolutely avoid it.

Comment: I have occasionally had lists in my abstracts. My group keeps them as part of the text i.e., "We show that 1) blah blah blah, 2) other stuff, and 3) this one thing."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One important thing to keep in mind is that the abstract is typically copied to various article databases, which have varying support for markup. As such, much of the formatting will not necessarily be carried over. That nicely formatted bulleted list which appears in the pages of the journal can turn into a confusing mess in online article databases. (e.g. It might lose the bullets and be smashed into a single paragraph.)

For this reason, it's generally recommended to avoid any special formatting in article abstracts - even things like italics should be kept *de minimis*.

If at all possible, skip the bulleted list, and keep the list in plain text format. If you *do* want to keep the bulleted list, be sure to format the list entries such that things stay readable even if the bullets are removed and everything is collapsed into a single paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

Abstracts are almost always formatted as a single paragraphs of plain text.  This is for stylistic reasons and because indexing databases often have limited formatting support. By stylistic reasons I am referring to the idea that journals aims for a consistent look for how papers are formatted. This consistency is presumably partly driven by tradition and convention. But consistency also helps readers quickly identify sections of a manuscript.

If you want a list in an abstract, use a standard inline list format such as:

**(a), (b), (c)**

> Results showed (a) blah blah blah, (b) blah blah blah, and (c) blah blah blah

or 
**(1), (2), (3)**

> Results showed  (1) blah blah blah, (2) blah blah blah, and (3) blah blah blah

Comment: @FedericoPoloni okay. I tweaked to make it more of a stand-alone answer.

Comment: Still not clear to me what you mean by "for stylistic reasons". Do you think that 'inline bullets' are stylistically better than normal bullet points with proper spacing around them? Or is it a "because we've always done like that" reason?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni updated a little

Answer (score 2):

There is a stylistic tool that allows for listing in text and looks perfectly natural, the semicolon.

> The semi-colon allows you to list: your results, which might also
>   require some additional explanation to be put after a comma; other
>   people results'; some previous results and pretty much anything else.

This is one of the function of the semicolon, so it should not cause style issues and it should not cause any markup issue either!

Comment: Lists formatted with a semicolon (or with "inline numbers" as suggested in [@JeromyAnglim's answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/79100/958)) are less readable though, especially if the additional explanations are long. If properly-formatted bullet lists were supported everywhere, they would be a superior solution in my view.

Comment: I agree, this is one possible solution when markup and/or appropriateness are a concern under the condition that the items are not too long.